# Send two different email with attachement with phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I've a problem and I can't figure out where is.
I've form that will send two different mail:

1. a simple thank-you-mail that need to be delivered ONLY to who has compiled the form, with an attachement
2. a second mail that need to be delivered ONLY to the owner of the website, that will reply, with the same attachement

My problem is that, with phpmailer, the client that compiled the form is receiving both mail. And of course he doesn't have to see the second mail.

here's my code:

```
$to = $email; 
$subject = "Princype - la tua configurazione"; 
$message =
"Buongiorno $nome, <br>
in allegato potrai trovare le tua configurazione per il tuo $taglio $style.
<br>
A breve entrerai in contatto con un nostro incaricato breve per confermare o fissare un appuntamento.
<br>
Cordialmente,
<br><br>";




// email stuff 2
$to2 = "info@info.com"; 
$subject2 = "Princype - richiesta info per $taglio $style - $id_planimetria"; 
$message2 =
"Una nuova richiesta per l'appartamento $taglio $style - $id_planimetria,
<br>
<br>
Nome: $nome <br>
Cognome: $cognome <br>
email: $email <br>
Telefono: $telefono <br>";



//first email
try {

    $mail->isSMTP();                                                    // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtps.XXX.com';                               // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                           // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'info@info.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'XXXXXXX';                             // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                                          // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port       = 000;                                            // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('info@info.com', 'info service');
    $mail->addAddress($to, sprintf('%s %s', $nome, $cognome));           // Add a recipient

    $mail->addReplyTo('info@info.com', 'info service');


    // Attachments
                  // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment($filepath, $filename);                            // Optional name

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                                   // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $message;
    $mail->AltBody = $message;

    $mail->send();

    //second mail
    $mail->setFrom('info@info.com', 'info service');
    $mail->addAddress('info@info.com', 'info service');           // Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo($to, sprintf('%s %s', $nome, $cognome));


    $mail->Subject = $subject2;
    $mail->Body    = $message2;
    $mail->AltBody = $message2;

    $mail->send();
    // echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log( "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}");
}}?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `addAddress` will append an e-mailaddress to the already known list of receivers. You should clear the list of receivers before adding any more if you dont' want multiple receivers, this can be done with the following snippet,

```
$mail->clearAddresses();
```